# how to send data from controller to include/header blade file but return another blade file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to include send my data from my controller to my `header.blade.php` file in view
but i want to return the other view in the laravel as mentioned below:-

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user(); 
    $finduser = User::where('google_id', $user->id)->first();

    if($finduser) {
        Auth::login($finduser);
        $google_avatar = $user->getAvatar();
        view('pages.home',['google_avatar', $google_avatar]);  
        return redirect()->route('home',);      
    }
}
```

Comment: fyi, `view('pages.home',['google_avatar', $google_avatar]);` will have no effect, you `redirect()` to a different page afterwards. Also `return redirect()->route('home',);` will throw errors because of that comma in there.

Answer (score 0):

By [extending a layout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-a-layout) is the cleanest way.

From the docs:

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The child:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Page Title')

@section('sidebar')
    @parent

    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

By just returning the "child" view from the controller, the data will be available in the header as well. If you pass it in the `@extends` declaration

Comment: yess,but i just want to send the data in the header which is in the extends('layout.pp')

Comment: @NavjotSingh You can pass data like this: `@extends('layouts.app', ['x' => $y])` I will add that more clearly